# Ocultar imagen En Fragment

Tags: android-studio

Tengo la siguiente parte de mi código:

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.llanterna_fragment,
                    container, false);

            ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.estrellaOn);
            ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.estrellaOff);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {

                    switch (v.getId()){

                        case R.id.estrellaOn:
                            //Apretar mostramos texto
                         //   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Activar flash!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                            //ocultamos estrella
                          //  getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                          //  estrellaOn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                          //  estrellaOff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                            break;

                        case R.id.estrellaOff:
                            //Apretar mostramos texto
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Desactivar flash!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            //mostramos estrella

                            estrellaOff.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            break;


                    }

                }
            });
            return view;
        }
```

En el layout he creado dos imágenes:
Estrella On y Estrella Off

La idea es que cuando le de al boton EstrellaOn se esconda y muestre la que esta oculta. Pero no lo consigo.

Que hago mal?

saludos,

Comment: estrellaOn en realidad no lo estas ocultando...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes de implementar el onclick listener al fragment:

```
 public class TuFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener { ...
```

te va pedir que implementes el método onClick.

En onCreateView asignale el listener a los botones:

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
button2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

El método onClick debe quedar así:

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.button:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Activar flash!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Desactivar flash!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
    }
}
```

Otra forma es sin implementar el onclick listener y asignar el onclick
directamente a cada botón:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
        }
    });

  button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
        }
    });
```

Comment: gracias!!! ahora si! ^^